# Real-time shared document preview with markup tools in web browser using HTML5 and ASP .NET MVC back-end

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, html, html5-canvas, webrtc

I have an issue with shared document (pdf, docx, xlsx) viewing and marking tools (simple line, shapes, arrows) for ASP .NET MVC web site using HTML5 capabilities. I need to implement some kind of google docs within website so the end users can view and put marks to the same document and see it is being marked at the browser window for all other users viewing such document at real-time. The best solution is to use some kind of peer-to-peer communication without server-side to be involved (like WebRTC). All markup functionality seems to be done using HTML5 canvas. Document storage on the server is not mandatory. All marks are stored within the connection session.

For now I have found some pretty complex and expensive approaches like crocodoc and groupdocs that actually provide much more functionality that is needed for my project.

Please suggest anything that can help me with my goal achieving

Thanks for all responses!

Answer (score 0):

for Real-time interaction you can use [SignalR](http://asp.net/signalr)

> ASP.NET SignalR is a new library for ASP.NET developers that makes
>   developing real-time web functionality easy. SignalR allows
>   bi-directional communication between server and client. Servers can
>   now push content to connected clients instantly as it becomes
>   available. SignalR supports Web Sockets, and falls back to other
>   compatible techniques for older browsers. SignalR includes APIs for
>   connection management (for instance, connect and disconnect events),
>   grouping connections, and authorization.

Comment: Thank you, for response! SignalR is websockes client-server interaction library. I am rather looking for front-end approaches for viewing\marking documents then for interaction with server.

Comment: You could use FlexPaper to collaborate your documents, its got a API and some sample scripts in ASP.NET to get you started

http://flexpaper.devaldi.com/

Comment: Thank you! Does FlexPaper support real-time multiple users document viewing\marking? The shared document usage is a key feature of my issue

Answer (score 0):

For pure peer-to-peer, you can use the webRTC API.

http://www.webrtc.org/reference/architecture

Be aware that peer-to-peer is low level architecture. You will be required to code capabilities that the server normally handles for you: cross-browser compatibility, API hooks, firewall tunneling, session maintenance, etc.

BTW, although you appear to be steering away from client-server architectures, client-server is very useful during real-time synching of html canvas commands that are simultaneously coming in from multiple clients.

One extremely thorny problem that is solved using a central server is time stamping the commands from each client. Without timestamping, canvas drawing commands will be issued in different orders across different clients. This results in the clients not having identical displays.

So my recommendation--given that you're using asp.net MVC is to use SignalR. SignalR uses a server to act as a seamless conduit to allow client-to-client communications. It is client-server that acts like peer-to-peer. But SignalR also handles all the required low-level capabilities for you.

Comment: Thank you, for all suggestions! May be you can also suggest some front-end framework\library for viewing\marking in real-time for some particular users?